# Где подлежащее?

Tags: синтаксис

Скажите, пожалуйста, в данном предложении подлежащим будет выступать сочетание *выражение лица*?

> *У него было каменное выражение лица*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Спорный случай. С  одной стороны, есть в медицине термин **выражение лица** (facial expression), значит, мы можем разобрать сочетание как один член предложения.

С другой стороны, в русском языке это сочетание употребляется как свободное: выражение лица, мимика лица; выражение глаз, выражение вашего лица.

Вот в этом предложении **явно подлежащее "выражение"**: *При этом лицо выглядит более моложавым, а его **выражение** становится приветливым.* Значит, слово **выражение** самодостаточное, может употребляться самостоятельно, у него есть значение "внешний вид" - вид лица, вид глаз.

Я бы всё-таки подчеркнула как подлежащее существительное **выражение.**